# Access Shopify API from an External App

Tags: shopify

I am trying to access the Shopify API from an external app that I am building (mobile). For example, I would like to access this API:

```
https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
```

Of course I would need to authenticate my request first. So far everybody I asked (including Shopify support), suggested that the only way to access the data is through a Shopify App.

Can you suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. Follow these steps if you want to access the Shopify API from an external app:

1. Login to your store as an admin
2. Go to Apps
3. Create a Private App
4. Use the following pattern with every URL you create (I am using this to get all the orders)

   https://:@.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json

The API Key and the password appear in your private app info page.